# Keystore updation trouble

Tags: flutter, firebase, oauth, android-keystore

I had to create a new keystore bcoz i didnt know the password to the original one (debug). I am building a small budget tracker app for which i wanted to enable Google and facebook login. For that initially i generated the SHA1 fingerprint for OauthClient etc . and done all teh work and it was working. Now facebook required some hash key for which i had to know the password for my keystore .

after numerous tries i gave up and created a new keystore. I updated the new SHA1 keys for my google Oauth2 Client at the google cloud console and even added the same SHA1 fingerprint to the firebase as well . However now for some reason google login isn't working and its throwing the following error
[image: Error]

It was written in the google cloud console that " Note: It may take 5 minutes to a few hours for settings to take effect "

Am i being impatient or do SHA1 fingerprint changes do really take time to update ?
Any thing else which i should have updated after generating a new keystore but didnt do (a sort of checklist) please do tell ...

**Details of keystore :-
new keystore name was mintle.jks (mintle after the app i am making) in location C:\Program Files\Java\jdk-18.0.2.1
**

I fear i might have to redo the entire thing again

Comment: https://support.google.com/googleplay/android-developer/community-guide/243925915/how-to-request-a-new-upload-key?hl=en